# List of most useful NLP resources and tools

Tags: discussion

The following is an **intentional and invited duplicate** of [a posting on English.Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3591/2085).  Alenanno nicely asked that I please post it here, too, so here ya go.  Three things that probably need fixing:

*Feel free to edit this main posting to adjust for non-English-specific tools.*

---

We already have lists of general-reference resources, [one on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573) and [a larger one on main](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1482). For the most part, these are things like dictionaries and thesauri, not actual tools related to natural language processing (NLP) or computational linguistics (CL). I would like to assemble a list of the most useful tools that come in handy for ELU.

These range from simple two-edged swords like Google Ngrams and the fancier corpus-analytic tools like the BNC or COCA (both of which require some sophistication to use), all the way up to tools for doing part-of-speech (POS) assignments, as well as stemmers, lemmatizers, chunkers, and syntactic analysers (‘parsers’).   There are a lot of other interesting ELU-related things it would be nice to know where to find the tools for, too.

For example, given this sentence:

> Yes of course the car whose headlights were off was running is right.

One can use the **CMU Link Grammar Parser** via [the CGI form here](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html) to generate this parse:

```
(S Yes
   (S (PP of course)
      (S (NP (NP the car)
             (SBAR (WHNP whose headlights)
                   (S (VP were
                          (PRT off)))))
         (VP was
             (VP running is
                 (ADVP right)))))
   .)
```

However, another approach is to use the [**DependenSee visualization tool**](http://chaoticity.com/dependensee-a-dependency-parse-visualisation-tool/) to generate a PNG of the dependency graph of a given sentence using the [**Stanford Parser**](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), which looks like this for that same sentence:

[image: dependency graph of sample sentence]

Please add a separate answer for each tool, and include both the link and a small demo of what that tool is good for.  I find the graphical tools especially useful, and I think a lot of other people do, too: witness the fascination with Google N-grams.

We can use the voting system as a way of showing which tools we think are most or least useful.

Comment: You couldn't find the button because only Mods can convert questions to Community Wiki, while answers can be posted as CW by the users that write them too. I added the tags.

Comment: I'll fix the question later to tailor it to the site.